# How to split a string (input) and each section used as a dictionary value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to write a program that checks if the DNA is mutated or not, i'm not quite sure how to explain this, so this is what it says: 
***Write a program to determine if a patient has a mutation in their DNA sequence which results in a change of amino acid sequence. Your program should work like this:***

```
Enter original DNA: AAT
Enter patient DNA: AAC
The patient's amino acid sequence is not mutated.

Enter original DNA: AATTGTTCTTCT
Enter patient DNA: AACTGCAGCTCA
The patient's amino acid sequence is not mutated.

Enter original DNA: TGTCATGCCTTATTAGAAAACGGTGAG
Enter patient DNA: TGTCATGTCTTATTAGAAAAAGGTGAG
The patient's amino acid sequence is mutated.
```

And this is part of the text file I use:

```
The mappings from codon to amino acid are available in a file, called codon_amino.txt, an excerpt of which is shown here:


AAC N
AAG K
AAT N
GCG A
GCT A
GGA G
GGC G
GGG G
GGT G
```

So this is my code so far:

```
n = {}
for line in open('codons.txt'):
    codon, codons = line.split()
    n[codon] = codons


org = input('Enter original DNA: ')
pat = input('Enter patient DNA: ')

if n[org] == n[pat]:
    print("The patient's amino acid sequence is not mutated.")
else:
    print("The patient's amino acid sequence is mutated.")
```

So my code works OK with the first example, where there are only 3 letters being used, but the next two have more than 3, and I was wondering how I could manipulate my code to work with that too? I hope someone understands this question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this the same as this assignment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541215/how-do-you-access-a-list-in-group-of-3-in-python - looks like you have your answer...

Comment: You have to split the input string into bits of three, and check all bits.

Comment: Essentially what you need is [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the codons one by one (strings slices are your friend here), and check the condition for all of them.

```
mutated = False           # First, assume no mutation is present
for index in range(0, len(org), 3):
    if n[org[index:index+3]] != n[pat[index:index+3]]:
        mutated = True    # Set mutation flag to True
        break             # Abort the loop - no point in checking any further
if mutated:
    print("The patient's amino acid sequence is mutated.")
else:
    print("The patient's amino acid sequence is not mutated.")
```

This assumes that both `org` and `pat` are of the same length, divisible by three. You might want to insert a check beforehand to make sure this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(org), 3):
    if n[org[i:i + 3]] != n[pat[i:i + 3]]:
        return "The patient's amino acid sequence is mutated."

return "The patient's amino acid sequence is not mutated."
```

Comment: This works! except when I attempt the longest example, It gives me `The patient's amino acid sequence is mutated.
The patient's amino acid sequence is mutated.
The patient's amino acid sequence is not mutated.` Instead of just the first line, how do I change that?

Comment: That would happen if you used `print` instead of `return` (which requires wrapping the above code in a function).

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```
n = {}
for line in open('codons.txt'):
    codon, codons = line.split()
    n[codon] = codons


org = input('Enter original DNA: ')
pat = input('Enter patient DNA: ')

if len(org) + len(pat) % 3 or len(org) != len(pat):
    raise ValueError

if any((n[org[i: i+3]] != n[pat[i: i+3]] for i in xrange(len(org)))):
    print("The patient's amino acid sequence is mutated.")
else:
    print("The patient's amino acid sequence is not mutated.")
```