# Reorder Python List

Tags: python

I have a list of 4 items like this:

```
a, b, c, d = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm reordering the list, flipping each pair:

```
[b, a, d, c]
```

Is there a way to do this in one expression? I've tried using list comprehension and unpacking, but can't seem to get it right.

I have [1, 2, 3, 4]. I'm trying to get [2, 1, 4, 3].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2493980/1628832 ?

Comment: can you elaborate what your desired input and output are?

Comment: Don't you mean to expect `[2,1,4,3]` as output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More generically, if you're looking to flip pairs of numbers in a list:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(L[1::2], L[::2])))
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at this:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [y for x in zip(*[iter(lst)]*2) for y in x[::-1]]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
>>>
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> [y for x in zip(*[iter(lst)]*2) for y in x[::-1]]
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: Slick. Going to have to spend some time figuring out how this works.

Comment: @nathancahill - Thank you.  I assume you understand the list comprehension parts.  What I did with `zip` and `iter` is a very helpful trick you should memorize (it's used a lot and will _really_ help you).  Here is a reference on it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541215/how-do-you-access-a-list-in-group-of-3-in-python  Scroll down to @abarnert's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If this is only about 4 member lists - this would suffice:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
reordered_list = [list[1], list[0], list[3],list[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because absolutely nobody has given an answer that works on generic iterables,

```
from itertools import chain

items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

zip(*[iter(items)]*2)
#>>> <zip object at 0x7fd673afd050>

[itms for itms in zip(*[iter(items)]*2)]
#>>> [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

So `zip(*[iter(x)]*2)` means `ix = iter(x); zip(ix, ix)` which pairs each element.

Then you can reverse:

```
[(y, x) for (x, y) in zip(*[iter(items)]*2)]
#>>> [(2, 1), (4, 3), (6, 5), (8, 7), (10, 9)]
```

Putting it all together and flattening:

```
[itm for (x, y) in zip(*[iter(items)]*2) for itm in (y, x)]
#>>> [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9]
```

It's generic *and* short!

---

If you want something faster at the expense of genericism, you'll be hard pressed to better this:

```
new = list(items)
new[::2], new[1::2] = new[1::2], new[::2]

new
#>>> [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9]
```

Note that this still works on arbitrary iterables, but there are fewer layers of abstraction; you can't bump up the size of the flipped sub-lists as easily and can't output iterables, etc.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for breaking it down step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
>>> a, b, c, d = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b, a, d, c = a, b, c, d
>>> a
2
>>> b
1
>>> c
4
>>> d
3
```

?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to reassign the variables, I'm trying to get [2, 1, 4, 3] from [1, 2, 3, 4]

Answer (score 0):

Try this list comprenhension solution:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6] # Any list with even number of elements
b = [a[e+1] if (e%2 == 0) else a[e-1] for e in range(len(a))]
```

This just works if the list `a` have an even number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [2]: list(chain(*map(reversed, zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))))
Out[2]: [2, 1, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? Reorder `given_list` with a loop:

```
rez = []
for i in range(len(given_list)-1, -1, -1):
    rez.append(given_list[i])
return rez
```